# Android Studio freezes when opening project on Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04, android-studio-3.0

Whenever I start Android Studio and click on "open existing project" the file explorer opens, but then the whole application immediately freezes. 
Im using Android Studio 3.1.3 and Ubuntu 16.04.

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: It is not freezing. It is downloading SDK components. Sometimes it takes an hour. I would suggest you to wait.

Comment: No, there is nothing getting downloaded

Comment: Try deleting project `.idea` folder and `.AndroidStudio3.1` config folders.

Comment: This worked for me! After deleting the .AndroidStudio3.1 folder and restarting, AndroidStudio suggested me to switch to a higher version of Java, which resolved the problem. Tanks!

Comment: @YaroslavMytkalyk Please write an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of misconfiguration, closing Android Studio and deleting `.AndroidStudio3.1` configuration folder may help.

[Find your configuration files | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#file_location)

In some similar scenarios of misconfiguration deleting `.idea` folder might help.

Answer (score 5):

There could be several reasons for this behavior. The first that comes to my mind is whether or not your hardware/OS meets the recommended specs - you can find the recommended specs below, taken from Android Studio's site:

- GNOME or KDE desktop - Tested on Ubuntu® 14.04 LTS, Trusty Tahr (64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications)
- 64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications
- GNU C Library (glibc) 2.19 or later
- 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator
- 2 GB of available disk space minimum,
  4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
- 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

You could determine whether or not memory/CPU usage is the problem by issuing the following command when Android Studio is running:

```
-$top
-[SHIFT+M] (key combination that sorts processes by highest memory usage)
-[SHIFT+P] (key combination that sorts processes by highest CPU usage)
```

Bear in mind that the most likely memory offender of Android Studio will be Java and that's what you'll see in the top command output. If your memory usage is high, it's possible that your OS will start to use swap space which could significantly slow things down. To see how much swap memory is being used, issue the following command:

```
$free -h
```

This command will show you, at the time the command is issued, how much RAM and swap memory is being used in a human-readable format.

Another possibility that I have not experienced personally but have seen others have issues with is connected USB devices. Perhaps you have your phone connected - if this is the case try unplugging your USB connected device and then issue the following commands from a terminal (within the android_sdk/platform-tools directory):

```
$./adb kill-server
$./adb start-server
```

If you're not sure where the platform-tools directory is located, you can issue the following command:

```
$locate platform-tools
```

If Android Studio seems to start up/run without issue when the device is not connected, try reconnecting the USB device and see if the problem recurs.

It's also possible that what you're seeing is keyboard-related - i.e. the application stops responding to keyboard-input - this may be related to a known issue with the iBus Daemon - possible workarounds can be found at the following link:

http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus

If your problem is determined to be resource usage - it may be necessary to add more memory. If that is not the issue, it might be worth trying to completely reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: When I run the command `watch -n 5 free -m`, I got the following results: *total: 7717, used: 6810, free: 140.* shortly followed by a freeze.  Does that mean that memory usage is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Delete from command line the .android folder `sudo rm -r /pathOfAndroidRootFolder/.android`.

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate caches and restart option :

File -> Invalidate caches and restart

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting .AndroidStudio folder and check, because some java update might be needed for Android 3.1.3